# ${props.title} showing instead of showing the Title - Layout.js in Next.js during page navigation

Tags: javascript, next.js

The page is not rendering correctly when I navigate using the href from Index Page. Its show props.title instead of showing the Title. Have provided the code for this. I am trying the instructions in the link - [Trying instructions in this link](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-dynamic-pages/passing-data)

[This is the Index Page from where we navigate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXK38.jpg)

[This is how the page is rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN5oq.jpg)

[This is the expected behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLefs.jpg)

Index.js

```
import Layout from '../comps/MyLayout';
import Link from 'next/link;
const PostLink = props => (
  <li> 
    <Link href={'/post?title=${props.title}'}>
      <a>{props.title}</a>
    </Link>
  </li>
);
export default function Blog() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>My Blog</h1>
      <ul>
        <PostLink title="Hello Next.js" />
        <PostLink title="Learn Next.js is awesome" />
        <PostLink title="Deploy apps with Zeit" />
      </ul>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Layout.js

```
import Header from './Header';
const layoutStyle = {
  margin: 20,
  padding: 20,
  border: '1px solid #DDD'
};
const Layout = props => (
  <div style={layoutStyle}>
    <Header />
    {props.children}
  </div>
);

export default Layout;
```

Post.js

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Layout from '../comps/MyLayout';
const Page = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>{router.query.title}</h1>
      <p>This is the blog post content.</p>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Comment: You should displaying plain code instead of images.

Comment: Did you read documentation about dymanic routing? https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-dynamic-pages

Comment: @ManUtopiK - Of course. In fact, I was trying to follow the instructions given in this link. Let me know if I am missing anything in this. I am fairly new to JS :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change simple quote by backtick like so:
`` <Link href={`/post?title=${props.title}\`}> ``

This is [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).